# Armitage error, could not connect to database

Tags: lubuntu, metasploit

The following error messages  appear while starting ARMITAGE:

i cant found a database.yml file i really need it.
hre how to fix this:

1. try setting MSF-DATABASE-CONFIG to file that exists
2. did you use sudo to start this program? try sudo -E
3. kali linux 1.x users try this :

service metasploit start
service metasploit stop

kali linux 2.x users, try this:
msfdb init

(Am using LUBUNTU distribution)

Answer (score 0):

I went through this problem too, this is how I solved:

1. Check the location of your database.yml file, it could be in 2 places:
   /opt/metasploit-framework/
   /home/youruser/.msf4/
2. Then set the variable MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG to that location:
   export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/thelocation
3. Finally, launch the armitage as root, while preserving the user enviroment:
   sudo -E armitage

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem was solwed by runing this:

```
sudo msfdb init
```